# How to interpret this sample space set?

Tags: probability

As part of one of my Random Signal Theory assignments I came across the sample space of random variables X and Y represented by the set:

$S_{X,Y} = \{(x_i,y_j):(i,j),i,j=1,2\}$

How would I interpret this? What I think it means is:
"Sample space $S_{X,Y}$ contains $x_i$ and $y_j$ such that $i$ and $j$ can take the values $1$ or $2$"

Which would result in the sample space containing 4 variables: $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$

However I am mostly going on intuition and lack a true understanding of how exactly to construct and interpret this sort of notation.

Another option in my mind is that it is somehow specifies that:
$x_1=1, x_2=2, y_1=1, y_2=2$
Which would fit the context of the problem, but again I have no idea how to derive this meaning from the above statement.

Can someone please explain exactly what this does mean and/or point me in the direction of learning resources that would teach me the basics of understanding this set notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would interpret this as the set of pairs $(x_i, y_j)$ with $i,j = 1, 2$. Explicitly, the set
$$
S_{X,Y} = \{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_1), (x_1, y_2), (x_2, y_2)\}.
$$

Comment: That makes sense given the context of the problem, but surely there are definite "grammar" rules to this notation. Is that correct? I still struggle with seeing exactly why that translates as such. I now see that the parentheses indicates that there are pairs, but why are the i and j in parentheses followed by a comma and then they are repeated not in parentheses before the equals sign?

Comment: Personally, I would have written the set as $S_{X,Y} = \{(x_i, y_j), i,j = 1, 2\}$, avoiding the colon and the $(i, j)$. It would be a lighter notation. In general, when you have real numbers $a,b$, the notation $(a, b)$ indicates the pair formed by the two numbers in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: You can read that as "the space of pairs $(x_i, y_j)$ such that the pairs $(i, j)$ have coefficients $i, j$ taking values $1$ and $2$".

Comment: You have been very helpful, thank you for your time! Is that understanding something you just develop over time, or is there any resource that could teach me the definite rules of this notation? Also it looks like I may have asked too basic of a question or possibly failed to word it well given the downvote. Should I edit the question in any way to make it more acceptable?

Comment: I don't know about the downvote, I didn't give it to you. Maybe yes, the question was indeed too basic to be appreciated by the community. I wouldn't rephrase it since you found an answer. Regarding the math understanding, I guess it's just experience. I suggest you read math texts, you will get more and more acquainted to the language of mathematics!